# Transparent PNG over labels and textboxes on my .Net form

Tags: vb.net, image, png, transparency

I have a project where I want to place a png on the form like a "Rubber Stamp". I have the transparent *.png but I need it to be transparent on TOP of all the textboxes, labels, etc. Every time that I use a label or picturebox to hold the image, you still see the form background. It's not being brought transparent on top.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: what? You have an image or something? Cannot understand what you're asking for...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question right, let's say you have a PictureBox called PictureBox1, and a Label called Label1, and you've placed PictureBox1 in front of Label1, and the PictureBox has a transparent background. In the form's load event:

```
PictureBox1.Parent = Label1
```

If this doesn't work, try adding

```
PictureBox1.BringToFront()
```